# Display one random testquestion in every div tab

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to php and Im working on a skill test project. My objective is to display one random question from mysql database in each div tab without duplicating the questions. My current problem is that same question is displayed in every tab. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you so much!

Here is my code:

```
         <?php   
           $servername = "localhost";
           $username = "root";
           $password = "";
           $dbname = "palo";
           $conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
           if(!$conn){
             die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
           }
           $sql = "SELECT test_id, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond FROM tquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";      
           $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql); // Run the query
           if (!$result) {
              printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
           exit();
           }
        ?>

        <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
        </script>

        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q2')">2</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q3')">3</button>
        </div>            

        <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['msg'])) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div id="q1" class="tabcontent">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($result as $results):?>
                        <tr class="form-group">   
                            <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $results['question']; ?> </h3>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="form-group">
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiona'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiona'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionb'];?>"><?php echo $results['optionb'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionc'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" ame="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiond'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="q2" class="tabcontent">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($result as $results):?>
                        <tr class="form-group">   
                            <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $results['question']; ?> </h3>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="form-group">
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiona'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiona'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionb'];?>"><?php echo $results['optionb'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionc'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" ame="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiond'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly ordering your query when you use

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

but you need to limit the results according to the total number you want to achieve, like

```
limit 0, 2
```

Even though you are using a foreach, you use the same record. You need to iterate for your records, like this:

```
     <?php   
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "";
       $dbname = "palo";
       $conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
       if(!$conn){
         die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
       }
       $sql = "SELECT test_id, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond FROM tquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";      
       $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql); // Run the query
       if (!$result) {
          printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
       exit();
       }
    ?>

    <script>
    function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q2')">2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'q3')">3</button>
    </div>            

    <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['msg'])) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-info"><?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

            <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
            <?php $index = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($result as $results):?>
    <div id="q<?php echo ($index++); ?>" class="tabcontent">
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
                    <tr class="form-group">   
                        <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $results['question']; ?> </h3>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiona'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiona'];?> 
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionb'];?>"><?php echo $results['optionb'];?> 
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionc'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?> 
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" ame="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiond'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in there? Cannot just foreach on a mysqli_query result like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your immediate response sir @Lajos Arpad! I tried the codes you suggested and it finally worked!